# Generar líneas según fecha PL SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Soy nuevo en SQL (pl sql Oracle) y me gustaría a partir de una tabla con campo fecha, generar las líneas necesarias entre la línea actual y la siguiente, siendo cada línea un día atendiendo al campo ID y al campo Money. Os muestro un ejemplo que creo que no me estoy explicando muy bien:

Tabla origen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría hacer (una muestra):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución, basada en CTE's, tiene las siguientes partes:

- Primero, una tabla creada al vuelo que simula los datos de tu tabla de origen, con los mismos datos de ejemplo de tu pregunta. He llamado los campos con nombres que no usan palabras reservadas en PL/SQL, de manera que no haya que usar "" en las consultas.
- Un generador de números consecutivos, de 1 a N. Para ello me estoy basando en la vista `all_objects`, que suele tener entre varios cientos a miles de registros en la base de datos típica. Si las distancias entre fechas pueden ser muy grandes o esta vista tiene pocos registros en tu base de datos, ajusta esta parte para que el generador tenga suficientes números para cubrir la máxima diferencia de días entre dos fechas.
- Un CTE que toma los datos de la tabla original y calcula el número de días que transcurren entre el registro actual y el siguiente en la tabla, que es el número de veces que cada registro se tendría que *repetir* en el resultado final. Para ello me valgo de la función *lead*, particionando por *id*.
- Finalmente, armo la respuesta, obteniendo primero todos los registros de la tabla original, a los que uno las repeticiones que hagan falta. Para crear estas repeticiones, hago *join* entre el resultado de `TablaDias` y el generador de números. Voy sumando el número a la fecha, para crear *al vuelo* la fecha correspondiente al registro.

La consulta queda así:

```
with 
Tabla(ide, fecha, dinero) as (
          select 500, to_date('2017-02-23', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 3500.00 from dual
union all select 500, to_date('2017-02-26', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 35000.00 from dual
union all select 500, to_date('2017-02-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 50000.00 from dual
union all select 200, to_date('2017-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 8888.00 from dual
union all select 200, to_date('2017-05-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 999.00 from dual
union all select 200, to_date('2017-05-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 1000.00 from dual
)
, numeros as (
select row_number() over (order by object_id) N 
  from all_objects
)
, TablaDias as (
select   ide
       , fecha
       , dinero
       , lead(fecha) over (partition by ide order by fecha) - fecha dias
  from Tabla
)  
select *
  from Tabla
union all  
select   TablaDias.Ide
       , TablaDias.Fecha + numeros.N Fecha
       , TablaDias.Dinero
  from TablaDias
       inner join numeros on numeros.N < TablaDias.Dias
 order by 1 desc, 2
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
IDE   FECHA       DINERO
==== =========== ========
500   23-FEB-17   3500
500   24-FEB-17   3500
500   25-FEB-17   3500
500   26-FEB-17   35000
500   27-FEB-17   35000
500   28-FEB-17   50000
200   01-MAY-17   8888
200   02-MAY-17   8888
200   03-MAY-17   8888
200   04-MAY-17   8888
200   05-MAY-17   999
200   06-MAY-17   999
200   07-MAY-17   999
200   08-MAY-17   999
200   09-MAY-17   1000
```

Puedes probar el script en línea: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/lrxdzmbtnkrrakkyjhafbvqac

Comment: Muchas gracias, perfecto!